# What is the difference in meaning between “I like it when you do this to me.” with and without the word “it”?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I saw this sentence on the internet: *“I like it when you do this to me.”* and I would like to know the difference in meaning between *“I like it when you do this to me.”* and *“I like when you do this to me.”*

Comment: There is no difference. I consider the first more idiomatic.

Comment: I consider the first more "syntactically valid". But this business about including the dummy pronoun "it" with various ***wh-*** words is a minefield for learners. Generally speaking we ***don't*** include the dummy - not many people would endorse it in *I like **it** how you smell, I hate **it** what you did, I know **it** why you lied*, for example. But *I hate [**it**] where you live* is a tricky one where I think both versions are fine (they're *parsed* differently, but end up meaning the same anyway). But mostly, ***when*** is the "special case" here.

Comment: ...I've just realised that although *I **hate** where you live, I **hate it** where you live* and *I **know** where you live* are all fine, ***I know it where you live*** doesn't sound remotely idiomatic to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica what about "I like it what you did to me"? :)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: *I know it what you mean!* :)

Comment: [This page](http://arts-ccr-002.bham.ac.uk/ccr/patgram/ch09.html) has some very useful stuff about "dummy it" in various contexts. They include several examples of ***it + when***, as in *I hate it when she's away*, but I see ***no examples at all*** of ***it*** followed by any other ***wh-*** word (they obviously wouldn't endorse, say, ***I hate it how you argue***). It seems to me that for most purposes it's enough to say "dummy it" is usually "correct" between *[verb of perception]* and a ***when-*** clause (and maybe ***where-***), but is usually "incorrect" with other wh- words.

Comment: I would say that "what" sounds like it refers to a thing, so is seen as a noun, (though I'm not sure whether it technically is or not), and therefore "I know what you mean" sounds right to most English speakers.  And, for the same reason, "I hate where you live" sounds borderline but probably OK, and "I love when you do that" sounds definitely wrong (at least, it does to me).

Comment: I love/like when is really folksy. I love/like it when you hold my hand.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is very subtle, and lies merely in focus of the sentence.

> I like when you do this to me.

Here, the focus is on **when**, meaning "I like the times that you do this to me."

> I like it when you do this to me.

Here, the focus is on the dummy pronoun **it**, or perhaps the combination **like it**.  This changes the focus to the liking itself.  "I very much enjoy the things you do to me."

Fundamentally though, both convey the same meaning, just with a *slightly* different focus.  And the difference is very slight.

Answer (score 0):

They're the same, one is just a contraction of the other.

Comment: They are the same in meaning, but they have a very different syntactic structure, so I don't think you can reasonably say that one is a contraction of the other.